# In the glm function for logistic regression, where is the likelihood function stored? Is it in family?

Tags: r, glm

I am currently trying to run a logistic regression on my own, using the functions `optim`, `nlm`, etc. However, I am somehow getting different coefficient values for the custom model as compared to when I run glm.

I suspect that my likelihood function might be different, but cannot find where the logit likelihood function is stored in `glm`. Does anyone know?

Comment: What you ask has been answered in this excellent post from @fg-nu, this is the likelihood function you should derive http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81000/calculate-coefficients-in-a-logistic-regression-with-r/81004

Comment: Please specify the context. If it's 'R', say it's 'R'. Update the title if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood function is not stored in the `glm` object. In R 3.1, only the following fields are present:

```
> m <- glm(y ~ x, data=df, family=binomial(link=logit))
> names(m)
 [1] "coefficients"      "residuals"         "fitted.values"    
 [4] "effects"           "R"                 "rank"             
 [7] "qr"                "family"            "linear.predictors"
[10] "deviance"          "aic"               "null.deviance"    
[13] "iter"              "weights"           "prior.weights"    
[16] "df.residual"       "df.null"           "y"                
[19] "converged"         "boundary"          "model"            
[22] "call"              "formula"           "terms"            
[25] "data"              "offset"            "control"          
[28] "method"            "contrasts"         "xlevels"
```

If you type `glm.fit` at the R prompt, you will see how the optimization proceeds. In particular, there is no separate likelihood function that can be evaluated with different points in the parameter space. See the link in Steve's comment for what you need to do.